# ffmpeg via pipe: stream 1, offset 0x30: partial file

Tags: go, ffmpeg

my videodata is dynamic it can use any exension but its error when i use mp4 extension.

my function:

```
func (s *service) convertVideo(videoData []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg",
        "-i", "pipe:0",
        "-c:v", "libvpx-vp9",
        "-b:v", "0",
        "-f", "webm",
        "-t", "8",
        "-preset", "ultrafast",
        "pipe:1")
    cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(videoData)
    cmd.Stdout = &buffer
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buffer.Bytes(), nil
}
```

and got error:

```
stream 1, offset 0x30: partial file
Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 720x1280, 773 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
```

is it because i use stream pipe? becuase if i use temp file its success, but its not that effective.

**New**

if i convert my mp4 to mp4 first, then it success. so the cause of problem is from my mp4, but still not found the solution in code.

Comment: `mp4` is compression mux type, then stream need can be seek, but stdin stream (`pipe:0`) can only read. You must try another mux type like `flv`.  And stdout stream(`pipe:1`) similar